# How to provide a menu bar only if it is displayed in a global menu bar?

Tags: qt, kde-plasma

I am writing an application use KDE and QML. The main window is going to be pure QML, with a very custom look, so I don't want a menu bar at all. I'm going to a have something like the Dolphin "Control" button, but implemented in QML. However, if the user has a global menu bar, like Unity or the KDE global menu bar, I would like to display a menu bar, so it fits in with other applications.

I notice this is the way the KDE file manager Dolphin works. By default, there is a "Control" button that has a limited set of the menus. However, if there is a global menu bar, the regular menu bar is exported, even though it is still set to not show the menu bar.

[image: Dolphin with global menu bar]

**How can I set the menu bar to only display if it is being displayed in a global menu bar? Can it be done in pure Qt or must I use KDE? If this is automatically provided by not showing the menu bar, how do I hide the menu bar?**

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the source code of Dolphin, this appears to be automatically handled by KDE (or maybe by Qt). If the menu bar is hidden, it will not be shown in the window frame, but if it is being exported to a global menu bar, it will be shown regardless of whether the menu bar is hidden or not.

To keep the menu bar from ever displaying in the window, but still display in a global menu bar, simply do this:

```
menuBar()->setHidden(false);
```

If you are using KDE and want a standardized way to hide/show the menu bar, you can use a `KStandardAction`:

```
KStandardAction::showMenubar(this, SLOT(toggleShowMenuBar()),
        actionCollection());
```

If you modify the toolbar, such as showing a control button, you probably need to do it specially (code taken from Dolphin):

```
KToggleAction* showMenuBar = KStandardAction::showMenubar(0, 0, 
        actionCollection());
connect(showMenuBar, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)),                   // Fixes #286822
        this, SLOT(toggleShowMenuBar()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Apparently, the special connect is needed because the slot will modify the toolbar (see [KDE bug #286822](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=286822)).

Answer (score 0):

It is easy enough to know if your application is minimized, maximized, just shown or fullscreen from inside Qt (see [`QWidget::windowState()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowState)).  Detecting the state of the OS or other nearby windows formally is OS specific.

One sort of "hacky" way to do it would be to check the size of the desktop (see [`QDesktopWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdesktopwidget.html#details)) and check the size of your maximized window and see if they are different by x amount in a single direction.  If they are, then you use your global menu bar / task bar mode, otherwise you go into your hidden menu bar mode.  But you may need to check this periodically in case they task-bar auto-hides.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. In the picture I just added, I have a widget in a KDE panel to provide a global menu bar. Dolphin is set to not show its menu bar (and doesn't without a global menu bar), but yet it is still displays in the global menu bar widget. That is what I would like. It should display regardless of the maximized/fullscreen state.

Comment: KDE's UI is almost completely written in Qt now.  OSX uses a global menubar like that and Qt uses it when you are running a Qt application on a Mac.  Normally when you aren't in QML, you just make a QMainWindow, and Qt just decides where to put the Menubar based on if you are compiling for Mac or Windows or Linux.